# Getting data from a csv and putting respective columns into a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

My CSV file:

```
sku,cost price
aba,8.32
abb,11.12
abc,34.34
abd,7.54
abe,3.54
abf,9.31
abg,8.22
```

What I am trying to do is creative a dictionary where the sku key returns its respective value, so `{'aba':'8.32}, {'abb':'11.12'}`, etc.

Comment: Hi @Scott! What have you tried yet?

Comment: You can address this issue via `pandas`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pandas (`pip install pandas`):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('your_file_name.csv', index_col=0)
df.to_dict()['cost price']
Out:
{'aba':'8.32', 'abb':'11.12', ...}
```